# What is wring with the way the information is presented in the graph?

Tags: statistics

I am not sure how to identify the misleading information in the graph. My only guess is that the percent numbers do not have the percent sign, making the numbers look like "actual numbers of truck owners".

[image]

Answer (score 2):

What is misleading to a layperson is the fact that the vertical scale does not start at $0$. While the graph seems to suggest large differences in customer satisfaction, it is actually the case that nearly all owners are satisfied (more than $94\,\%$ for *each* brand)

Comment: so what's misleading is that the graph does not start at zero, and the graph shows a large difference between Chevrolet and the two other brands, so the scale isn't correct either? If the scale was right, I think the spread wouldn't look that way.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an acronym that might help. All graphs gotta have SOUL:

S: Scale

O: Origin

U: Units

L: Labels

Comment: thank you. the graph doesn't clearly show it's starting point, whether it's 0 or another value. so does this mean that any statistical graph should start at 0, not at any value ?

Comment: Correct; Hagen's answer says the same thing. Generally you need to include the origin so that you have a good notion of the relative sizes of things.